# Disable Browser Rubber Band effect in Windows Phone 8 HTML5 App?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10, rubber-band

Does anyone know of a way to disable the "Rubber Band" effect in the IE10 browser on a Windows Phone 8 device? I tried a trick where I can create a high DIV and absolutely position it and then try and fix the position of the main content div, but IE10 seems to ignore that. It's hard to make an HTML5 app feel like an app when it giggles everywhere...

Answer (score 5):

Try adding -ms-touch-action:none for body as below:

```
<style type="text/css">body {{-ms-touch-action:none; }}</style>
```

Comment: This works well if all of your content is visible. If you need to allow scrolling but disallow the rubber-banding during overscroll, this solution will not fit the bill.